# MatLab: error when creating array with nodes names

Tags: matlab, graph

I'm trying to create a list of node names for a graph in Matlab; since the nodes are cells of a matrix, I want to name them as '[row][column]' where I put the number converted to text instead of the names; here's my code

```
K = N*N;
names = strings(N, 1);
for i=1:N
    for j=1:N
        names((j-1)*N+i) = strcat(num2str(i),num2str(j));
    end
end

moves = ones(K, K);
G = graph(moves, names);
```

This gives me an error:

```
Error using graph>validateFlag (line 527)
Option must be 'upper', 'lower', or 'OmitSelfLoops'.

Error in graph (line 217)
                        [checksym, omitLoops] = validateFlag(nnames, checksym, omitLoops);

Error in robot_movement (line 26)
G = graph(movements, names);
```

I can't understand why, since one of the ways to create a graph is by giving in input a matrix and a set of names.

Comment: There should be N names, not NxN.

Comment: The definition of the array is wrong, ok, but it's right to have NxN names: one for each cell. The description of the array names is in fact 1xN^2 string

Comment: As per doc, there should be N names. Moreover, the doc says names should be cellstr, not array of strings.

Comment: Then my problem is I can't create one with the names I want...is there a method?

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
G = graph(moves, cellstr(names));
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).